# Import code from extarnal file to HTML

Tags: html, xhtml

Say I have a text file (test.txt) that contains only the following line:

```
<h1>Text text text text text</h1>
```

Is there any command that I can call the contents from this text file in an HTML document, so the contents in the text file imports where the call is made, every time the side shows?

Example: ?????"/test.txt"?????

Comment: We are going to need more details...Like what language/framework are you using?

Comment: @Jonas B: Show that test.txt content in a html page?

Comment: What do you mean? My pages are in CSS3 & XHTML. Is it enough? Framework?

Comment: @Kerrek: Where do you see that...?

Comment: If you are using pure HTML, server-specific SSI extension may help you.

Comment: Simple, just use iframe to load that test.txt in a html page :)

Comment: Let me clarify a little. I have many pages with duplicate content. Eg menu bar. Would I change a link, I have to do it on all sides today. Therefore I am looking for a solution where I can call a file with code in the example menu bar, with a command of every page where the menu bar will be located.

Comment: @minitech: Referring to "every time the side shows"... but no worries, just a minor aside :-) @Jonas: SSI really sounds like the most straight-forward solution. @David: iframes are very different, they act like mini tabs and require a complete document, not just a snippet!

Answer (score 3):

I believe you mean to ask whether there exists a "command" in HTML which allows you to include a file.

In pure HTML by itself there does not, but the Apache **server-side includes** does provide such a directive:

```
<!--#include virtual="./test.txt" -->
```

You will need to enable SSI processing by your webserver. In Apache, you'd typically call your file `.shtml` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the concept call "Server Side Includes". Different servers will do this different ways, so you'll need to look at what your server provides.

Answer (score 1):

Not with pure HTML, but you can with PHP (and almost every other server side language):

```
<?php include("test.txt"); ?>
```

Or you can do it in a roundabout way with JavaScript if the file is part of the website, you're actually running a web server, and you're not worrying about older browsers:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ajaxRq = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
ajaxRq.open("GET", "test.txt", false);
ajaxRq.send(null);
document.write(ajaxRq.responseText);
</script>
```

Comment: That first one looks simple. Can a just put that php line in my XHTML page?

Comment: @Jonas: Yes, but only if you're using PHP and only if you've added the `.html` extension as PHP in your server configuration file.