# Trouble using AJAX request to include navigation menu

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, get

I am using an AJAX request written by @minitech here on Stack Overflow, and while it seems to work well within a single directory, when I try to call a page from another source (as in this case) to be loaded into the requesting page, some scripting (i.e. jQuery scripting) is dropped from the page being requested.

My question is: is there a way to have a file load before it is requested to be included into the requesting page? I am unable to use PHP due to restrictions at work, so Java is the preferred method.

This is the script I'm currently using;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ajaxRq = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    ajaxRq.open("GET", "abcde.html", false);
    ajaxRq.send(null);
    document.write(ajaxRq.responseText);
    </script>
```

This was submitted by @minitech some time ago; you can find the original source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565737/import-code-from-extarnal-file-to-html).

~

So to wrap things up: this works -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ajaxRq = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    ajaxRq.open("GET", "first/abcde.html", false);
    ajaxRq.send(null);
    document.write(ajaxRq.responseText);
    </script>
```

When the file that is making the request is located in the directory /first/

~

This does not work -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ajaxRq = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    ajaxRq.open("GET", "first/abcde.html", false);
    ajaxRq.send(null);
    document.write(ajaxRq.responseText);
    </script>
```

When the file that is making the request is located in the directory /first/second/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file is in `/first/second`, to reach `abcde.html` you can go two ways:

Absolute URL:

`/first/abcde.html`

Relative URL:

`../abcde.html`

If you request `first/abcde.html` will actually try to find a file at

`/first/second/first/abcde.html` which probably doesn't exist.

That's all I can think of with the information we have.